# Macro compilation

Tags: c, macros

I'm getting these error messages when compiling my code. I`m confused. I use clang compiler and code is written in C. The macro should interchange two arguments of type t.

```
Documents/program7.c:5:5: error: expected ')'
( t type = x; x = y; y = type; )
    ^
Documents/program7.c:5:1: note: to match this '('
( t type = x; x = y; y = type; )
^
Documents/program7.c:5:3: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
      [-Wimplicit-int]
( t type = x; x = y; y = type; )
  ^
Documents/program7.c:5:15: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
      [-Wimplicit-int]
( t type = x; x = y; y = type; )
              ^
Documents/program7.c:5:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'y'
( t type = x; x = y; y = type; )
                  ^
Documents/program7.c:5:22: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
      [-Wimplicit-int]
( t type = x; x = y; y = type; )
                     ^
Documents/program7.c:5:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'type'
( t type = x; x = y; y = type; )
                         ^
Documents/program7.c:5:32: error: expected identifier or '('
( t type = x; x = y; y = type; )
```

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(t,x,y) \

( t type = x; x = y; y = type; )

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    x = 2, y = 10;

    swap(int, x, y);

    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using "temp" instead of "type", which might be a reserved word.

Comment: statements in parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parenthesis around your macro:

```
#define SWAP(t,x,y) \
{ \
 t type = x; x = y; y = type; \
}
```

and it's case sensitive. So your macro invocation should be:

```
SWAP(int, x, y);
```

Having said that, I would make `swap` an inline function as opposed to a macro.

Comment: When is underscore used in macros?

Comment: The `swap` macro can't be replaced by an inline function without the use of templates. And that's a problem, since C doesn't have templates.

Comment: FWIW: The standard defines `{}` as braces. parenthesis are what OP already has. And this can break `if`/`else` compound statements.

Answer (score 4):

Replace your:

```
#define SWAP(t,x,y) \

( t type = x; x = y; y = type; )
```

with

```
#define SWAP(t,x,y) \
do { t type = x; x = y; y = type; } while (0)
```

and change the call:

```
swap(int, x, y);
```

to

```
SWAP(int, x, y);
```

A few notes in your macro definition: you cannot have the blank line after the `\` and also `()` can only be used between expressions and not between statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define SWAP(t,x,y) \

( t type = x; x = y; y = type; )
```

You have an extra blank line. Get rid of it. But, that will just give you more errors to fix later when you use the macro `SWAP`, since you cannot use parentheses like that.

The `do {} while(0)` idiom is useful for defining an inlined scope.

```
#define SWAP(t,x,y) do { t tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp; } while(0)
```

In your code:

```
    int x, y;
    x = 2, y = 10;

    swap(int, x, y);
```

You are calling `swap`, for which there is no macro defined. That should be changed to call `SWAP` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three separate problems with your code:

1. The code you intend as the macro replacement value is instead at top level because you interpose a blank line between the `#define` and the replacement text.  That soaks up the line-joining backslash.
2. You have a full semicolon-terminated statement inside parentheses (actually several).  Parentheses cannot contain statements, only expressions.
3. You try to use the macro via a lowercase name instead of via the uppercase name you defined.

You want something more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(t,x,y) \
do { t type = x; x = y; y = type; } while (0)

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    x = 2, y = 10;

    SWAP(int, x, y);

    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);

    return 0;
}
```